# docker-compose build stops because of large amounts of data in a folder

Tags: docker

I am running Docker on a vagrant machine with a shared folder with some data. In addition, I am using docker-compose to build images. In the root folder where the docker files are located some folders exist that hold (large amounts) of data. When these folders exist, the build process fails. When I temporarily remove the folder, they do succeed. Why does docker-compose go into these folders? Can I prevent that?

This is the docker-compose.yml section:

```
 frontend:
    restart: on-failure
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: php-lumen.dockerfile
    container_name: frontend
    ports:
      - "1010:80"
    links:
      - mongo
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - /data/data/frontend:/app
```

And this is the error:

```
 vagrant@dev:/data/results/orthology/tmp$ sudo docker-compose up --build frontend
 Creating network "data_default" with the default driver
 Building frontend
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 97, in create_archive
   File "tarfile.py", line 1980, in addfile
   File "tarfile.py", line 252, in copyfileobj
   File "tempfile.py", line 485, in func_wrapper
 OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "bin/docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
   File "compose/cli/main.py", line 71, in main
   File "compose/cli/main.py", line 127, in perform_command
   File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1080, in up
   File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1076, in up
   File "compose/project.py", line 475, in up
   File "compose/service.py", line 342, in ensure_image_exists
   File "compose/service.py", line 1082, in build
   File "site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 154, in build
   File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 31, in tar
   File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 100, in create_archive
 OSError: Can not read file in context: /data/data/large_data_file.tab
 [26820] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

Anyone?

Comment: With the output your provided it doesn't care about those sub folders but rather the device is simply full and it can't write new files.

Comment: Hi Seth, I don't think that's the case because when I move the folder out it does continue. Df -h also shows that there are some GBs available.

Comment: Where do you move it? From where? What does your `df` look like? Do you move that folder to another partition by moving it out of that directory? What is in that folder?

Comment: Yes I move the folder complete out of the vagrant context using Windows Explorer. I find this message strange:  OSError: Can not read file in context: /data/data/large_data_file.tab why does it even have to read that folder?

Comment: Because it's apparently creating some sort of archive and running out of space in the process. Why do you use the Windows Explorer if you're using a Linux machine? What does your actual build file look like?

Comment: I am using vagrant on windows to create a Linux development machine. On that development machine I have installed docker.

Comment: Please improve your question by including information about your setup and what you're doing. Include the build file for the docker image as what's within that might be relevant. Explain which paths are relevant and what they contain. Checkout the help section for some more information [on how to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).